# <embed> source changer with password

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to improve my gaming website, and I want to add a feature where when you press a button, you are asked to put in a password, and then a cheated version of the game comes up.  Here is the code I have so far. EDIT: I also do not care about the password being secure, so it is alright if it is obvious in the code.

```
<button type="button" onclick="cheat()">CHEAT!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var password;
var pass1 = "PASSWORD";

function cheat()
{
password=prompt("Password:","");
}

if (password==pass1) {
  document.getElementById("gamecheat").innerHTML = '<embed src="http://www.arcadeprehacks.com/swf/94562377.swf" width="550" height="400">';
} else {
  alert("wrong password");
}
</script>

<div id="gamecheat">
  <embed src="http://mybig.com/arcade/resources/f-1293.swf" width="550" height="400">
</div>
```

To view a working version on my website visit [www.thefunon.com/game-cheat](http://www.thefunon.com/game-cheat)

Comment: What's the problem here? I didn't test your code but basically seems alright. Another way to do it is to put your alt swf in html but set it to be invisible, and then just hide old one and make the other one visible.

Comment: Whenever I try the code, it doesn't work, I'm not sure what is wrong, I thought someone else could help.  I will try the hiding thing, but if I do this, then the other swf will already be loaded, this isn't necessarily a bad thing though.  Also, with this current code, the prompt will go off as soon as I load the page, that is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only setting the `password` inside the function. None of the other code is executed. You need to rearrange the logic, and this functions:

```
var password;
var pass1 = "PASSWORD";

function cheat()
{
    if(prompt('Password') == pass1) 
    {
        document.getElementById("gamecheat").innerHTML = '<embed src="http://www.arcadeprehacks.com/swf/94562377.swf" width="550" height="400">';
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert("wrong password");
    }
}
```

You can see a working jsFiddle [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ByxT/).